# When does Bash read heredocs?

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

I'm trying to understand the behavior of Bash when it comes to reading heredocs, as I am trying to implement a minishell based on bash in C.
I am using GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18), but the following applies to newer versions too (5.x) as I tested them.
Specifically, I'm interested in knowing the circumstances under which Bash reads the content of a here document (<<). I've encountered some scenarios where it seems Bash behaves unexpectedly, and I'd like to clarify these points.

When using a heredoc in a commad, how does Bash determine when to read the heredoc? For example:

`|||||| cat <<END`
In this case, Bash reports a syntax error (`bash: syntax error near unexpected token ||`) and doesn't read the heredoc. Why does this happen?
Conversely, in this other case, how does Bash handle it? For instance:
`cat <<END |||||||`
Here, Bash reports same syntax error but still reads the heredoc from stdin. Why does this behavior differ from the previous example?

I'm seeking clarification on these behaviors to better understand how Bash processes heredocs in different contexts.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is documented outside the bash source code so the best option may be to read the source code to get a hint.

Comment: `ls |& cat <<END` (With following text and an END so it's a proper heredoc) works for me; the heredoc redirection overrides the pipe from `ls` and so `cat` displays the heredoc text.

Comment: Sure you're using bash? It gives a syntax error in basic `sh` which doesn't understand `|&`.

Comment: You are trying to supply `cat` with data via stdin and via heredoc. You must choose one of the two.

Comment: @Shawn: `|&` was added to bash with version 4.0.

Comment: This question in based on a misconception, and is thus unanswerable: bash _doesn't_ read heredocs. Bash _writes_ heredocs, and connects them to the stdin of programs it starts; those programs may or may not read their stdin and access the content of that document at any point during their runtime that they so choose.

Comment: Also, when you say "bash reports a syntax error" _without showing us the exact error_, we don't know if it's because you're on a shell version too early to support `|&` or some completely different issue.

Comment: @Cyrus: Re “You are trying to supply `cat` with data via stdin and via heredoc”: No, they are not, because they are not actually trying to execute that command. They are using that command as an example of bash reporting a syntax error before reading the here document. (Except command does not report an error when I try it, and they have not indicated how the behavior indicates the here document was not read, but that is the apparent intent.)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: “Read the heredoc” means reading input, for use in a redirection, from the current source until a line containing only the designated word is seen